# SaveAs .rgba file extention

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I'm trying to do automate my file saving to saveAs file .rgba in photoshop. So far I only manage to modify the code to save out .sgi files. Please help. Thanks

```
var Name = app.activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/,'');
var Path = app.activeDocument.path;
var saveFile = File(Path + "/" + Name +".sgi");
var saveFile2 = File(Path + "/" + Name +".rgba");

if(saveFile2.exists)
{
saveFile2.remove();
}

rgbaSaveOptions = new SGIRGBSaveOptions();
activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, rgbaSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
saveFile.rename(Name+'.rgba');
```

Comment: maybe rename the file after? `saveFile.rename(saveFile.name.replace('.sgi','.rgba'))`

Comment: Yes. I had tried the replace function. did not work... I added it after the SaveSGIRGB function.

Comment: What didn't work? It worked for me, I did some tests. It seems that default extension for SGIRGB is sgi and it can't be changed in a script.

Comment: Yes. The script will export the .sgi file. However, I need it to save as .rgba file. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: no, you need to rename the file after using the `.rename` method

Comment: Sorry, I very new to scripting. I tried the rename method. Dont know why when I try the .rename on the sgi files, it just won't work. But when I tried on saving as png and run the .rename. It will work.

Comment: could you update your question with your final code that also has a `.rename()`? maybe there's an error somewhere

Comment: I just updated & added 'saveFile.rename("test.rgba")' on both inside the saveSGIRGB function and after it.

Comment: Your `saveFile` is `Name + '.rgba'`, but file saved has `.sgi` extension: so rename can't find it. Change `saveFile` to `Name + '.sgi'` and it should work

Comment:  Yes! it's working now. Because the Name + .rgba didn't make any difference from the start, so I did not think it will have any effect with .rename.  But now there is a new problem. It will only rename it once and won't overwrite the same .rgba file. It will create a new .sgi file

Comment: Yes, you need to remove the previous file first.

Comment: Sweet! I had updated the script. It working now. However, I think the script could have been written better. Can anyone suggest how? I just started playing with scripting so I am super new to this.